# Ranking variables (not observations)

Tags: stata

The questionnaire I have data from asked respondents to rank 20 items on a scale of importance to them. The lower end of the scale contained a "bin" in which respondents could throw away any of the 20 items that they found completely unimportant to them. The result is a dataset with 20 variables (1 for every item). Every variable receives a number between 1 and 100 (and 0 if the item was thrown in the bin)

I would like to recode the entries into a ranking of the variables for every respondent. So all variables would receive a number between 1 and 20 relative to where that respondent ranked it.

Example:

**Current:**

```
               item1 item2 item3 item4 item5 item6 item7 item8 etc.
respondent1    67    44    29    7     0     99    35    22
respondent2    0     42    69    50    12    0     67    100
etc.
```

**What I want:**

```
               item1 item2 item3 item4 item5 item6 item7 item8 etc.
respondent1    7     6     4     2     1     8     5     3
respondent2    1     4     7     5     3     1     6     8
etc.
```

As you can see with respondent2, I would like items that received the same value, to get the same rank and the ranking to then skip a number.

I have found a lot of info on how to rank observations but I have not found out how to rank variables yet. Is there anyone that knows how to do this?

Comment: See http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0046 But you are probably better off with a  `reshape long` -- after which you can rank within respondents directly.

Comment: Certainly use a `reshape long` first. There is a reason you can find info on how to rank observations but not how to rank variables. For this type of task, a data set in long format is your best bet.

Comment: Cross-posted at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1338010-ranking-variables-instead-of-observations In any forum, it's polite to flag cross-posting (and indeed widely considered out of order not to do so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution using `reshape`:

```
/* Create sample data */

clear *
set obs 2
gen respondant = "respondant1"
replace respondant = "respondant2" in 2
set seed 123456789
forvalues i = 1/10 {
    gen item`i' = ceil(runiform()*100)
}
replace item2 = item1 if respondant == "respondant2"
list


     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     |  respondant   item1   item2   item3   item4   item5   item6   item7   item8   item9   item10 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | respondant1      14      56      69      62      56      26      43      53      22       27 |
  2. | respondant2      65      65      11       7      88       5      90      85      57       95 |
     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


/* reshape long first */
reshape long item, i(respondant) j(itemNum)

/* Rank observations, accounting for ties */
by respondant (item), sort : gen rank = _n
replace rank = rank[_n-1] if item[_n] == item[_n-1] & _n > 1

/* reshape back to wide format */
drop item // optional, you can keep and just include in reshape wide
reshape wide rank, i(respondant) j(itemNum)
```

Comment: Thank you ander2ed! It worked perfectly and I understand how it worked. You just saved me from a lot more hours of headache. Just a little addition of a problem I ran into: I believe that if you decide not to drop `item`, you have to take it into the reshape wide: `reshape wide rank item, i(respondant) j(itemNum)`

Comment: Discussion at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1338010-ranking-variables-instead-of-observations